# assigning color to dc.js scatter plot interferes with selection in the graph

Tags: dc.js

I am trying to use a single colorScale accross several charts, including a scatterplot.  Everything shows up correctly as shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/za8ksj45/8/

```
Uncomment line 210 --> working selection but no colors.
comment line 210   --> colors but selection 'empties' other graphs.
```

However, when I select point in the rightmost scatter plot, everything is 'zeroed' out.   Things go wrong the moment you add a third element to the dimension.

This issue is also decribed in the DC.JS google user group under 'Color scatterplot based on third variable' https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dc-js-user-group/55nJcU0qDfg

I could not get it to work using Gordon's .existenceAccessor function. Any help to allow colors as well as selection would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
--Nico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color is not logically part of the key.  You really want to reduce two values here, the count and the color.  This requires a custom reduce function (or [reductio](https://github.com/esjewett/reductio) might make it easier).

You can just grab the color from the first value you see for a bin.  Presumably there will only be one value per bin anyway, which is always an odd thing about scatter plots in crossfilter.

This custom reduction seems to work (somewhat hacky):

```
var scatterGroupDate = scatterDimensionDate.group().reduce(
    function (p, v) {
        p.count = p.count ? p.count + v.setupTime : 1;
        p.color = v.recipe;
        return p;
    },
    function (p, v) {
        p.count -= v.setupTime;
        return p;
    },
    function () { return {}; }
    );
```

with colorAccessor

```
.colorAccessor(function (d) {
    return d.value.color;
})
```

and existenceAccessor

```
.existenceAccessor(function(d) { return d.value.count; })
```

Forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/za8ksj45/11/

Comment: Thank you Gordon.  That makes sense and you're right, in most cases (that I can think off) there is one color per bin.   I really appreciate your answer to mine and many other dc.js posted questions.  It has helped me tremendously to understand the library better and to get some things implemented quickly.  (cannot plus this as answer as I lack the  reputation points but it is exactly what I needed.  Will uptick when I get a couple more reputation points)

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem (the green checkmark).  We both get a little rep that way, and it helps me when I'm scanning the list of questions to see them checked off.